# How to write <a href="mailto: tag in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I am creating HTML o/p using xsl. one of the requirement is to display user's mail id and when clicked... it will open a new page of Outlook.

I know tag but How to write HTML tag in xslt ?

```
<a href="mailto:<xsl:value-of select="//Email/>">
 <xsl:value-of select ="//Email"/>
</a>
```

where Email is retrived from an XML. I need to provide xpath but it is thorwing error.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<a href="mailto:{//Email}">
  <xsl:value-of select="//Email"/>
</a>
```