# XSL: Parsing XML to HTML - How do I use value-of an element data as an html attribute?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

```
<input src="LOGO.JPG" type="image" name="imagem">
```

I have an xml element that contains the image path that needs to be displayed in HTML after the parse.
`<xsl:value-of select="image"/>` returns the string that is stored in the image element but how can I use it to make that string be the src atribute value in an html tag?
I tried `<input src="<xsl:value-of select="image"/>" type="image" name="imagem">` but obviously that doesn't work so how can it be done?

I hope I was clear in my question. Please help!

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857352/how-to-write-a-hrefmailto-tag-in-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="image" name="imagem" src="{image}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="image" name="imagem">
    <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="image" /></xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

Comment: I get the error "Unexpected atribute" and select="image" highlighted in my editor. I tried a various combination of xpath expressions and this error persisted.

Comment: The select attribute on xsl:attribute was introduced on XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?:

```
<xsl:template select="//image">
    <xhtml:img>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of="@name" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of="@src" /></xsl:attribute>
    </xhtml:img>
</xsl:template>
```

Remember to bind the namespace prefixes correctly. Also, img elements in HTML *must* have an alt.

alternatively replace "//image" with the specific Xpath to your XML element.